# file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64):

Tags: xcode, architecture, arm64, carthage

I'm seeing this error when trying to run my Xcode project with the PaperOnboarding.framework on my iOS device:

```
.../PaperOnboarding, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /(mypath)/PaperOnboarding
```

The app works on the simulator, so I thought I might fix the issue by changing the Valid Architecture list, but the list already has arm64 as a valid architecture in my build settings.

Also, I looked around and found that I have to set my "Build Active Architecture Only" setting to "No" in order to fix this issue like so:

[image]

But even after doing this I'm still seeing the same issue when trying to build the app on my device.

Any idea how to fix this?

Also, I'm using Carthage.